# Batch to FIND and REPLACE with inputs from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a Batch File that will find a string and replace it with a string that comes from a notepad file

For Example:

I have the following content in XYZ.txt

<Xml 3.0>
set bjuih
fjgfgfr
GA JHJA KSKASA
Set Oid value = '**1.2.3.456.7**'
gshdasdsad
end

I want the number mentioned in bold to be replaced with a value that will come from a file with name ABC.txt

I was able to write the below code; however it is not working as expected.

```
@echo off
SET InFile=C:\Test\Apple\XYZ.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "1.2.3.456.7 "%InFile%"') DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
pause
goto :eof
:FindString
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:1.2.3.456.7=abc%
echo.%String%>C:\Test\Apple\XYZ.txt
```

Need assistance ASAP to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type "%sourcedir%\abc.txt"') DO (
  SET "replacement=%%a"
  FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('type "%sourcedir%\xyz.txt"') DO (
   SET "line=%%b"
   CALL :subs
   IF DEFINED line ECHO %%b
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:subs
SET "newline=%line:SET Oid value=%"
IF "%newline%"=="%line%" GOTO :EOF
SET "line="
ECHO Set Oid value = '%replacement%'
GOTO :eof
```

This batch simply reconstructs the file as `newfile.txt`. I used `.` as my target - you'd need to substitute your directoryname.

Note that you can't update a file in-place - you have to create a new file (`newfile.txt` in this batch`and then`move`it over the original version (`move /y` will replace without asking).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, i was able to write the following code using your given code however it doesnt seem to work all it gives is a blank screen on the command prompt..pls help

Comment: "@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Test"
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type "%sourcedir%\oid.txt"') DO (
  SET "replacement=%%a"
  ECHO '%replacement%'
  FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('type "%sourcedir%\ACDM%%a\Adapter.dll.config"') DO (
   SET "line=%%b"
   CALL :subs
   IF DEFINED line ECHO %%b
   Pause
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
move /-Y "%sourcedir%\newfile.txt" "%sourcedir%\ACDM%%a\Adapter.dll.config"

:subs
SET "newline=%line:SET Oid value=%"
IF "%newline%"=="%line%" GOTO :EOF
SET "line="
ECHO Set Oid value = '%replacement%'
GOTO :eof"

Comment: Move your "move" line to before the `goto :eof`, not after it. The `goto :eof` jumps to the end of the batch, so the `move` isn't being executed. Because the output is being redirected to `newfile.txt`, the prompt from your `pause` will not be visible (it is redirected to `newfile.txt`) and your `echo '%replacement'` will also be sent to the file - but with the added twist that because of the way batch works, all you'd see is `''`- because `replacement` is not defined when the "block" statement is encountered. See `delayedexpansion` in endless SO items for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that in a plain cmd batch file, but if you can use PowerShell, I've had a similar issue before, the solution for which I documented here:

http://tangodude.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/powershell-multiple-find-replace-in-files-with-lookup-list/

The PowerShell snippet is:

```
Param (
    [String]$List = "ReplacementList.csv",
    [String]$Files = ".\Files\*.*"
)
$ReplacementList = Import-Csv $List;
Get-ChildItem $Files |
ForEach-Object {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName;
    foreach ($ReplacementItem in $ReplacementList)
    {
        $Content = $Content.Replace($ReplacementItem.OldValue, $ReplacementItem.NewValue)
    }
    Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $Content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
>abc.txt echo 888.777.666
SET "InFile=C:\Test\Apple\XYZ.txt"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("abc.txt") do set "newstring=%%A"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%InFile%") DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
move newfile.txt "C:\Test\Apple\XYZ.txt"
pause
goto :eof
:FindString
SET "String=%~1"
if not "%string:Set Oid value=%"=="%string%" (
      >>newfile.txt echo Set Oid value = '%newstring%'
  ) else (
      for %%z in ("%~1") do >>newfile.txt echo %%~z
)
```

Comment: You are right - try it now.  I've fixed typos and corrected other errors, and tested it.